# Springboot Actuator info end point redirecting to login page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, info

When I hit my springboot actuator info end point , it is getting redirected to login page instead of showing the info details .

Here's  what I have in my `application.yaml` :

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info,loggers"
  info:
    java:
      enabled: true
```

However , my actuator health end point is working . Anyone know what I am missing ?

I am using Springboot 3.1.1 .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Spring Security. This is the intended behavior. If your application uses Spring Security all endpoints other than the heath endpoint are protected. See the actuator documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security) that speaks to when Spring Security is on the classpath.